# Getting error in getDownloadUrl() showing error message canot reslove method'getDownloadUrl()'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

getting error in `getDownloadUrl()` showing error message canot reslove method `getDownloadUrl()`

[image: error]

Comment: Not much to go on, ... code samples and the precise error text would be more helpful.  If you comment out the offending call does the program still work or is this just the tip of the spear?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the `UploadTask.TaskSnapshot` doesn't even have a `getDownloadUrl()` method, but I am not sure since I cannot see the whole code. 
As you can see here [UploadTask.TaskSnapshot](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot) the class doesn't have that method but if you have built something custom it might be something else.

It might also be that you are in a static context and in that context you cannot reference a method depending on an instance that might not exist. The static method is loaded when the class is loaded. The method doesn't depend on the class's instance.